# GI-Gtk callback threading

Tags: multithreading, haskell, gtk

I am having an issue with threading when using callbacks in GI-Gtk. Consider the following program:

```
import GI.Gtk hiding (main)
import GI.Gdk
import GI.GLib
import GI.GLib.Constants

import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk 

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    t <- myThreadId
    putStrLn $ "init "++show t

    Gtk.init Nothing

    d <- dialogNew
    dialogRun d
    onWidgetDestroy d onDestroy

    Gtk.main

onDestroy :: IO ()
onDestroy = do
    t <- myThreadId
    putStrLn $ "onDestroy "++show t
    runOnGUI $ putStrLn "Destroying"
    putStrLn "Destroyed"
    Gtk.mainQuit

runOnGUI :: IO a -> IO a
runOnGUI action = do
    ans <- newEmptyMVar
    threadsAddIdle PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE $ action >>= putMVar ans >> return False
    takeMVar ans
```

When running the above program, the program hangs when I attempt to close the window, and I get the following output:

```
init ThreadId 11
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
onDestroy ThreadId 12
```

Looking at the code alone, I would expect to see this deadlock if runOnGUI is being called from the main thread (which I would expect it to be). However based on the output, runOnGUI should be getting called on a different thread, and therefore avoid the deadlock.

In my actual program, I attempt to avoid this type of deadlock by guarding runOnGUI in a `if currentThread /= mainThread` type conditional; but, as the above example shows, that does not appear to be sufficient.